# relationship between categorical feature and continuous target feature

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence, data-preprocessing

I'm working on house pricing model correspond to competition on Kaggle.
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques.
I found a lot of missing values in categorical data. some of them are more than 60% missing and other 47%.

I read that before dropping them I need to see the relationship between them and target feature (continuous). but, I couldn't measure the relationship between categorical features and continuous numerical target features.

I dropped features has missing values more than 60%.

coming to feature with 47% missing. I confused to drop it or not. and to know dropping it or not depend on the relationship between the target that I don't know how to calculate.

I searched a lot. and can't find only "Spares man rank" and it has to be complete data before calculating so I imputed it with KNN and then calculate. give me 0.1 so I dropped it.

I don't know what should I do, and what i did is right or not, please help

- my Question : how can I calcualate the relationship to make decision wheter or not drop categorical features

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to clarify it more. please tell me the ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to iterate thoroughly starting with simple methods to more complex ones in order to find the best way to impute the missing values in your data.

I would first recommend you to set up a pipeline (data processing, model fitting and evaluation) that is rigorous (using cross-validation, avoiding [data leakage](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/common_pitfalls.html#data-leakage-during-pre-processing), etc). You fix the choice of the model that you learn, e.g. a linear regression to begin. Then you try different methods for handling NaN and assess their impact on the predictor performance. Exploratory data analysis is also useful to understand the data.

You can handle the missing values as you did (dropping the features if the percentage of missing values exceeds a threshold, dropping lines, interpolating values, etc). There are plenty of methods but to evaluate correctly if they are right for your problem matters the most.

You can have a look at [imputation of missing values](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html) (note that some [estimators handle missing values](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values)) and [feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html).

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I'm quite beginner. all what I know about pipeline that it is for streaming data. my data is not streaming so I don't understand why you recommended to set up a pipeline. I took your advice and try several methods for handling missing values for  less than 18% and works fine

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, by pipeline I meant that some kind of automated process from reading the data, pre-processing it and fitting a model. It is useful for fast experiments and comparibility. Check for instance the one from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)